# Azure web app service time zone change issue

Tags: timezone, cloud, azure-web-app-service

We are using azure web app service for multi tenant application. But default time zone of app service is UTC taking i want to change that time zone for that region only.

I have tried WEB_TIMEZONE variable in app setting but not working.

Comment: Does my answer helps you?

Comment: In general, you should not be relying on the time zone setting of the environment, but rather specifically handling time zones in your application.  Take the UTC time from the server, and convert it to the desired time zone using the features of your application platform.

Comment: Hi, any progress about this issue now?

Comment: Hate when OP asks for something and never returns. Moderators should grant the solution to @abdul-rauf

Comment: @JayGong Yes it helped.. Thanks for this..

Comment: @paresh You could mark the answer for others' reference.

Comment: You can accept answer using the big checkbox. http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Answer (score 86):

You are setting wrong variable. You need to set `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` variable in `Application settings`. [image] 
To see supported timezone values see [this](http://jackstromberg.com/2017/01/list-of-time-zones-consumed-by-azure/)

To verify that whether offset is updated or not navigate to `Console` and execute `time` command [image]

**Reference:**
https://kvaes.wordpress.com/2017/01/24/changing-the-timezone-on-your-azure-webapp-app-service-function/

Comment: @andrej how are you getting time in your java app? Ensure that particular java method that you are using is reading local time from environment.

Comment: @AbdulRauf my azure appservice is in north europe region and I am getting GMT times. My user is in GMT+1 region and the logs using org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(My.class); LOGGER.debug("Hello, world!"); are in GMT

Comment: @andrej have you verified using `time` command that whether timezone is updated or not? if its updated and your app is still showing time in UTC than you may need to change settings of your Logger

Comment: Just got caught out by this. I'd assumed it would by default take the timezone of the region the App Service it was based in (in my case UK West) but obviously not :)

Comment: WARNING: To reuse the UTC time, you need to set the value to empty then save ! Indeed if you delete the WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE setting parameter and save the config, the previous WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE exists still...
If you delete it, you can refresh the config view to see it reappear in the configuration list.

Answer (score 10):

You could add an application setting (using the portal) called `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` equal to the name of the time zone
(as defined in the Windows Registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows Nt\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\`).

for example:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

If your App Service Plan is Linux change you need to set **TZ** variable in **Application settings** with your time zone in format like **America/Sao_Paulo**

Don't forget save and restart App.

Example:
[image: example]

List of time zones in: https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Thanks. That helps with datetime in container. Although .Net core 3.1 app stills gives GMT time.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the situation I went through.

Answer (score 2):

For Asp Core, you must use the variable name `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` instead of TZ

- If running on linux, use [tz database name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
- If running on Windows, use [windows server time zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones)

Example

```
+-------------------+---------------------------+------------------+
|   Variable name   |          Windows          |      Linux       |
+-------------------+---------------------------+------------------+
| WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE | AUS Eastern Standard Time | Australia/Sydney |
+-------------------+---------------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the other answers, you can find the Default Windows Timezones here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones

You need to set the value contained in the column "Timezone".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux Consumption set **TZ** variable in Application settings.
Example:

```
TZ: America/Sao_Paulo
```