# Azure Service Plan - Web app not working after time change

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I couldn't read into my storage account from an azure function I run locally or remotely. I update the time in my pc (it hadn't updated when the time changed tonight) and it resolved to work locally but I still can't read remotely.

Can you please clarify how this works? My service plan, web app, azure function, storage account are all in the UK South. Since last night we are at British Summer time in UK south (UCT+1). I check the time for the web app in portal on console and shows UCT.

Ofc I want the web app to work at different regions. Do I need to update the web app time on console every time the time changes, do I need to change a setting for this to happen automatically because it's not setup by default, or should I make the change at service plane level so azure function and storage account also update? or do I need to change the [WEB_TIMEZONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760325/azure-web-app-service-time-zone-change-issue) in my app, and if so to what time considering the user may run the web app from any region? thanks a bunch

Comment: It should work. Time Zone affect on timetrigger in azure function, but should not affect on read or write storage account. Which kind of trigger your are using in your azure function?

Comment: Hi @BowmanZhu I'm using HttpTrigger . My pc is now +1 hour versus my web app

Comment: Have you try to set the timezone? But to be honest timezone should not affect reading Storage Account.

Comment: Timezone refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749073(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Add `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` in Configuration Settings on Azure can change the time.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting changing the time for web app with WEB_TIMEZONE. I can make the times of my pc and web app match. There is no British Summer Time (GMT+1) so I can set GMT WEB_TIMEZONE in function app , but then when the time changes again in the UK to GMT (instead of BST =  GMT+1) do I need to adjust WEB_TIMEZONE in the function app again? I can run the function app on VS locally and it reads the storage account but it fails to read the storage account when I fire the function app as a redirect instructed by my web app

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kFku.png) is GMT + 1, use `Central European Standard Time` as the value of `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE`. Yes, you need to change the time zone when needed. For 'you cannot read storage account', have you already add the settings of storage account on azure? The settings of local.settings.json will not be deploy to azure.

Comment: thanks @BowmanZhu somehow local settings had not populated remotely. Works now :)

Comment: I have post a answer to this question. If my advice helps you, can you mark it as the answer to end this question?:)

Comment: Please notice that local settings will not populated remotely. It is only for local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timezone refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749073(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Add WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE in Configuration Settings on Azure can change the time.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kFku.png) is GMT + 1, use Central `European Standard Time` as the value of `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE`. Yes, you need to change the time zone when needed. For 'you cannot read storage account', you need to add the settings of storage account on azure. Because the settings of local.settings.json will not be deploy to azure.(It is only for local.)